# Pressure to current conversion

Tags: current-measurement, conversion, transducer, pressure, modelling

I was trying to convert the pressure values (in psi) into 4-20mA current. The range of pressure values I have chosen is between 0-10Psi. But according to the link given below the pressure from 3-15Psi is converted to 4-20mA. Does that mean that I cannot use the range 0-10Psi

https://instrumentationtools.com/example-of-3-15-psi-to-4-20ma-conversion/amp/

Comment: The link is for 3 to 15 psi. If you want something different, the link you provided makes no sense.

Comment: Depends on the sensor. If you have one which measures 0-15 psi and you want to translate that to 4-20 mA, you can.

Comment: Is your sensor 0-10 PSI? The link you provided is for converting pressure signaling to/from current loop signaling. If you have a pressure sensor that puts out 4-20 mA, that link doesn't apply. Pressure signaling is only used in old systems.

Comment: @Andy aka... the link provided is for 3-15psi itself. But my question is there any restriction that the pressure cannot be less than 3Psi. I am a M.tech student and this question was asked to me by my lecturer. I have taken the low limit to be 0Psi and high limit to be 10Psi. But my lecturer told that the pressure conversion to 4-20mA can be done only for 3-15Psi and how could I do it for 0 Psi. I did not have any answer for that

Comment: I am using ABB 266HSH

Comment: @Ujwala - that part number covers many variations of sensor models. Exactly what model do you have? Does it put out 4-20 mA? Some models put out 1-5V.

Comment: @Mattman944 the output is 4-20mA

Comment: i think that your lecturer may be asking you a mechanical question

Comment: @jsotala what do u mean with the mechanical question here?

Comment: OK, then 0 PSI will output 4 mA, 10 PSI will output 20 mA. Your teacher is confused, or trying to confuse you.

Comment: @Mattman944... Even I told him the same... But he was not at all ready to accept it... He was simply telling justify it justify it. Moreover I am not even applying this pressure i.e 0-10Psi to the sensor at all. I just found out the conversion data.. that's it